# Proving a formula for $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j^k}{f'(x_j)}$ for $f$ an $n$-th degree polynomial with $n$ distinct real roots $x_j$

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

If polynomial $f(x)=a_0 x^n+a_1 x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1} x+a_n$ has $n$ different real roots
$x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$, prove the following fomular:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{x_j^k}{f^{\prime}(x_j)}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0, & 0 \leq k \leq n-2 \\
a_0^{-1}, & k=n-1
\end{array}\right.
$$

**My answer for the first case is :**

I use the following Identity
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(x_{j}-x\right)^{k+1} l_{j}(x) \equiv 0,0 \leq k \leqslant n-2
$$
where $l_j(x)$ is Lagrangian Basis, more detail
$$
l_{j}(x)=\prod_{i=1 \atop i \neq j}^{n} \frac{\left(x-x_{i}\right)}{\left(x_{j}-x_{i}\right)}
$$
we know from the problem conditions that $f(x)$ can be writed as
$$f(x) = a_0(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$$
then we can get the following identity
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(x_{j}-x\right)^{k+1} \frac{f(x)}{\left(x-x_{j}\right) f^{\prime}\left(x_{j}\right)}\equiv 0
$$
Since $f(x) \not\equiv 0$, let $x = 0$ , then we get
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{x_j^k}{f^{\prime}(x_j)} = 0 $$ for the $0\le k \le n-2$

Now I am stucking in the second case and don't know how to prove it, I think it
can be prooved from the following Identities
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\sum_{j=0}^{n} x_{j}^{k} l_{j}(x) \equiv x^{k}, \quad k=0,1, \cdots, n \\
\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(x_{j}-x\right)^{k} l_{j}(x) \equiv 0, k=1,2, \cdots, n
\end{array}
$$
where $x_j$ are different points

Comment: I don’t have access to paper right now but after some imagination, I believe experimenting with small cases might give insights. Also, writing $f(x)$ as product form with leading coefficient 1, then the derivative $f’(x_j)$ is sum of many terms, most of which are 0 except for one. So, $f’(x_j)=(x_j-x_1)(x_j-x_2)\cdots (x_j-x_{j-1})(x_j-x_{j+1})(x_j-x_{j+2})\cdots(x_j-x_n)$. Sorry if this doesn’t help..

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very close approach is to use [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). For any $k\geqslant 0$ we have $$\frac{x^{k+1}}{f(x)}=p_k(x)+\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{a_{k,j}}{x-x_j},$$ where $p_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1-n$ if $k\geqslant n-1$, and $p_k(x)\equiv 0$ otherwise. And $$a_{k,j}=\lim_{x\to x_j}(x-x_j)\frac{x^{k+1}}{f(x)}=\frac{x_j^{k+1}}{f'(x_j)},$$ giving $$\frac{x^{k+1}}{f(x)}=p_k(x)+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j^{k+1}}{f'(x_j)}\frac{1}{x-x_j}.$$

Observe that $p_{n-1}(x)$ is a constant, easily seen to be $1/a_0$ after taking $x\to\infty$.

Taking $x\to 0$, we get what we need. One has to be careful if $k=0$ and $f(0)=0$ though. The LHS is then equal to $1/f'(0)$, and the RHS is missing exactly the term for which $x_j=0$.

Comment: Nice argument!!

Comment: That's great !!! Thank you.